# Quitar caracter a una cadena en php

Tags: string, php7

Tengo la siguiente cadena:

```
$cadena="2020-05-02";
```

Y lo quiero convertir a:

```
$cadena_nueva ="2020-05-2";
```

¿Qué función necesito emplear?. ¿Cómo se haría?. 
Muchísimas gracias por ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Si sabes que la fecha va a venir en ese formato, puedes descomponerla según el separador y analizar si en la ultima parte el primer caracter es un cero. En el caso de serlo (08), le cambias el valor por el del segundo caracter (8).

```
<?php

$cadena="2020-05-02";
$arr_fecha = explode('-',$cadena);
$arr_fecha[2] = $arr_fecha[2][0] == '0' ? $arr_fecha[2][1] : $arr_fecha[2];
$new_cadena = implode('-',$arr_fecha);
echo $new_cadena;
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias por el aporte, la explicación y por tu ayuda. El código, funciona de maravilla. Mil gracias, Cooper

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que vas a manejar son fechas y necesitas ese formato especifico partiendo de texto, quiza tambien te funcione asi:

```
$cadena = "2020-05-02";

$cadena = date("Y-m-j",strtotime($cadena));
```

Comment: funciona perfectamente !!. Muchísimas gracias por el aporte y la explicación. Un abrazo, Josue